# Compiler doesn't use operator<<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a little problem putting my linked list to the << operator. Here's the code:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o,const Node& f)
{
    Node *p = new Node(f.val);
    p->next = f.next;
    p->prev = f.prev;
    o << "[";
    while(p->next->val != -1)
    {
        p = p->next;
        o << p->val << " ";
    }
    o << "]" << endl;
    delete p;
    return o;
}
```

So when I use it in main() it looks like this:

```
BiQueue bq();
bq.Push(5);
...
cout << bq.getFirst();
```

But after testing, the operator just doesn't run, the output is a memory address.
So I tested it directly like this:
`cout << first;` (where first is a Node*) and it outputs a memory address, so the operator haven't been used.

Comment: Have you declared `ostream& operator<<(ostream& o,const Node& f)` as friend function inside class BiQueue ?

Comment: Yes it is a friend function

Comment: Unrelated: dynamically allocating a node object just to be able to stream seems wasteful.

Comment: Unrelated but more serious: deleting a node that's part of the list that you're printing is not a good idea. After the loop, `p` doesn't point to the `Node` you allocated any more. (So you're also leaking that `Node`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You told the compiler how to print a `Node`, but you are printing a `Node *`. Those are different types. To get the behavior you want try `cout << *first;` and `cout << *bq.getFirst();`.

Answer (score 2):

> the operator just doesn't run, the output is a memory address.

Instead of this:

```
Node *first = ...;
cout << first;
```

You need this:

```
Node &first = ...;
cout << first;
```

Since otherwise you're passing a pointer to `operator<<`.